# How to check it elemets of an array are in another array

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference, array-intersect

I have an issue,
I have this array

`$items= array('ABC','DEF',GHI');`

and have another two arrays

`$array1 = array('ABC','DEF',GHI');`

`$array2 = array('DEF');`

$array1 should return `TRUE` because all elements are in `$items`

$array2 should return `FALSE` because 'ABC' and 'GHI' arent in that array

i've tried with `array_intersect` and `array_diff` but i cant get it,

```
  $result = array_intersect($items,$array1);
  $result = !array_diff($items,$array1);
```

Could you please help me?
Regards
Mario

Comment: What if `$array1` had other values like 'JKL' would it still be `true`?

Comment: that will be false,

Comment: Well then the arrays need to be exactly the same?  Just use `==` then.

Comment: All elements of `$array2` are in `$items`. Why is it false?

Comment: Sort the arrays and then use `==` if each has to contain all elements of the other.

Comment: I tried with == but if i change the order to 'DEF','ABC',GHI' that give me false, but it should be true, because it doesn't matter the order,

Comment: excelente @Barmar thank you

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

To see if the array contains at least all values in `$items`, just get all values from the array that are also in `$items` and compare it with `$items`:

```
$result = (array_intersect($array1, $items) == $items);
```

If you just need to compare the arrays:

```
$result = ($array1 == $items);
```

But why is this not working for you:

```
$result = !array_diff($items, $array1);
```

Comment: I tried with == but if i change the order to 'DEF','ABC',GHI' that give me false, but it should be true, because it doesn't matter the order,

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use array_diff, you can use the multidimensional arrays.

Put your arrays inside another array:

```
$items1= array(
    array(0=>"ABC", 1=> "DEF", 2=>"GHI"),
    array(0=>"ABC", 1=> "DEF", 2=>"GHI"),
    array(0=>"DEF"),
);
```

Check them with conditional statements:

```
if($items1[0]==$items1[1]){
    echo "true";
}if($items1[1]==$items1[2]){
    echo "true 2";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```